# startactivityforResult not working

Tags: android

```
     Intent bookIntent = new Intent(this,ParseJson.class);
         // bookIntent.setClass(TitanGallery.this,ParseJson.class);
          startActivityForResult(bookIntent,BOOK_SELECT);


        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
         {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
```

called activity

```
Bundle b  = new Bundle();
      b.putStringArrayList("str_array", values);
      Intent go_parent  = new Intent();
      go_parent.putExtras(b);
      setResult(RESULT_OK,go_parent);
      finish();
```

i have one activity that calls startactivityforResult and that activity gives a bundle with the  array. the sub activity is not getting called. i have reffered a lot of code for this but i am not getting where is my mistake. if you learned  folks could look into the matter please?

Comment: Did you register both these activities? (verify the manifest)

Comment: yes. i have added. the control is not getting into  the sub activity.

Comment: are you getting the toast ever ? mean when you called startActivityForResult at that time ?

Comment: no Dheeresh  i am not getting the toast as the control does not go to the sub activity

Comment: @PavanM.B.: sub Activity means previous Activity, right?

Comment: sub activity means called activity.

Comment: can you proivde the code of the complete TitanGallery and ParseJson activity here ?

Comment: Have you solved this ? I have the same problem..

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)  {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  if(requestCode == BOOK_SELECT && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}
```

Comment: Agarwal, on activity result does not get called. the sub acivity is not getting invoked.