# Why am I getting a null pointer exception when passing an ArrayList of strings from one activity to another?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, startactivityforresult

I am trying to get an arraylist in `ScanLocate` activity from an `UpdateLocation` activity.

I'm using `startActivityForResult` method to call the `scan` method which populates the ArrayList `wifiList`, I then want to send the ArrayList to the `Update Location` class.

I start by calling `startActivityForResult` in `Update Location`:

```
private void getScan(){
    //Create an intent to start ScanLocate
    final Intent i = new Intent(this, ScanLocate.class);
    //Start scanLocate with request code
    startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_READINGS);
}
```

Next, in `ScanLocate` I created the `sendData` method (note: the check confirms that the ArrayList data is intact at that point):

```
private void sendData(){
    //create a new intent as container for the result
    final Intent readings = new Intent(this, UpdateLocation.class);

    //check that data is in wifiList
    for(String s:wifiList){
        Log.v(TAG,"List Items: " + s);
    }

    //create bundle for string array
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putStringArrayList(key, wifiList);

    //add readings to send to updateLoc
    readings.putExtras(b);

    //set code to indicate success and attach Intent
    setResult(RESULT_OK, readings);

    //call finish to return
    finish();
}
```

The final part is back in `UpdateLocation` with the `onActivityResult`:

```
    @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent readings){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, readings);

    //check if request code matches the one set above
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_READINGS){

        //check if sendData() in ScanLocate was successful
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            //get the readings from the Intent
            Log.v(TAG, "HERE");
            result = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList(ScanLocate.key);
            Log.v(TAG, "HERE2");

            for(String s : result) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Location 5: " + s);
            }
        }else{
            //ScanLocate was unsuccessful
        }
    }
}
```

The first `"Here"` is displayed however it then falls down on the next line, `getStringArrayList()` throws a null pointer exception.

I have looked through the documentation and at previous questions on here and I cannot see what is going wrong.

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks.

Previous questions:

[startactivityforResult not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10751893/startactivityforresult-not-working)

[How to pass an ArrayList to the StartActivityForResult activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40334334/how-to-pass-an-arraylist-to-the-startactivityforresult-activity)

Comment: DId you debug this with the debugger tool ?

Comment: You can use `readings.putStringArrayList(key, wifiList);` no need for bundle.

Comment: `Intent readings`. Do not use `getIntent()` but `readings`.

Comment: Removing the bundles and using `readings.putStringArrayListExtra(key, wifiList)` as well as `readings.getStringArrayListExtra(ScanLocate.key)` resolved it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to call `getIntent()`, use the parameter provided by the method:

```
result = readings.getStringArrayListExtra(ScanLocate.key);
```